# How to create installers with Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, installation

I'm migrating a medium sized Java application's build from Ant to Maven. I could easily migrate the basic building stuff, but I would also like to create the installer packages from the Maven build. The easiest way would be to call the original Ant scripts through the Ant plugin, but I thought maybe I should look around first for some Maven support.

I'd need to create several different installers for different platforms:

- Windows 32/64 bit
- Linux 32/64 bit
- MacOS 32/64 bit

For Linux now I think we only have a tar.gz and some Bash scripts to start the daemons - a Debian/RPM package would be much nicer, maybe with dependent package definitions, too. For the Windows installers we use NullSoft installer. I have no idea how the MacOS bundle is assembled now.

Are there any tools out there to do this (or at least part of it) from Maven?

Comment: Out of interest, how did you go about and how have you found the migration?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd use the [IzPack maven plugin](https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/display/IZPACK/Compiling+Using+Maven) if you need a full-blown installer, or the [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) if you simply need to generate daemons for java services.

There are also plugins for [NSIS](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nsis-maven-plugin/), [Debian](http://mojo.codehaus.org/deb-maven-plugin/), and [RPM](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/) packaging, but using those means you have to maintain configurations for each platform, on the other hand IzPack allows you to generate an installer for Windows XP / Vista / 2003 / 2000, Mac OS X, Solaris, Linux and *BSD.

---

The appassembler plugin provides a goal to generate JSW daemons for each platform. Here is an example configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <execution>
    <id>generate-jsw-scripts</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>generate-daemons</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <daemons>
        <daemon>
          <id>myApp</id>
          <mainClass>name.seller.rich.MainClass</mainClass>
          <commandLineArguments>
            <commandLineArgument>start</commandLineArgument>
          </commandLineArguments>
          <platforms>
            <platform>jsw</platform>
          </platforms>              
        </daemon>
      </daemons>
      <target>${project.build.directory}/appassembler</target>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I also use Izpack for my windows distributions, but the linux installer created is not very linux like and the OSX installer is a very bad idea, I would use a separate installer for OSX.

Answer (score 2):

You could use IzPack and the IzPack maven plugin for that purpose. It works quite well for me:
http://izpack.codehaus.org/izpack-maven-plugin/

Comment: Trouble is that the resultant izpack created installer is not very linux like

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i get the question right. Have you ever tried maven assembly?

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

That was i my first idea for your question.

Answer (score 1):

There's some plugins out there that will do some of what you want.

[.deb](http://mojo.codehaus.org/deb-maven-plugin/)

[.rpm](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/)

[nullsoft](http://mindtreeinsight.sourceforge.net/releng/maven-nsis-plugin/usage.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into Installjammer - I don't see a maven plugin for it, but compared with izPack, it looks much more professional.

Answer (score 0):

[BitRock InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com) can be used with Maven (and other CI build tools) to generate Windows exe installers, Linux binaries/RPM/DEB and OS X installers. It is commercial but we have discounts for small companies/solo developers and free licenses for open source projects (Disclaimer, I am the author of InstallBuilder)