# Automating a Java-based Software Install on Multiple Windows Machines

Tags: java, windows, deployment, build, build-automation

I'm working with a Java project that needs to deploy to multiple windows servers. I'm trying to decide on the proper way to automate this. My first choice would be to go the cygwin/ssh route and use a deployment framework like fabric to automate everything.

**Can anyone provide other methods that could be used to accomplish the same goal, and reasons why that would be a preferred solution?**

Comment: Does your solution have to install Java (the JRE) also or just the java programs.

Comment: Yes, I think it has to cover JRE install as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try to generate MSI package and deploy it using [group politics](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102).

Probably, that topic is related to your: [Creating installers with
   maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378129/how-to-create-installers-with-maven)